# Ширина DIV внутри ячейки

Tags: html, css

В таблице есть ячейка, внутри которой есть DIV  с достаточно большим текстом.

Упрощенный код

```
 <table><tr>
<td style="max-height:115px;"><div style="display:inline-block; max-height:inherit;">
    ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ 
            ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ
             ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ
             ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ 
        ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ 
        ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ </div></td>
  </tr></table>
```

Ячейка таблицы увеличивается по высоте, мне нужно чтобы высота была фиксированной и в зависимости от количества текста ячейка увеличивалась по ширине. Надеюсь на помощь, спасибо.

Перепробовал диву ставить display:inline, max-height Для дива и таблицы, overflow-x и т.д. Никак.

ПС. Без таблиц не обойтись, все на дивах не предлагать. Спасибо

Comment: а если максимальная ширина и высота не вмещают контент? Что тогда?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно что нужно. Вот я что то сделал.

```html
<table><tr>
<td><div  style="height: 35px; max-width: 100%; overflow-y: scroll;">
    ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ 
            ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ
             ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ
             ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ 
        ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ 
        ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ </div></td>
  </tr></table>
```

Comment: необходимо, чтобы ячейка внутри таблицы расширялась по ширине в зависимости от количества текста. А по высоте была фиксирована.